# Can the ĝi pronoun be used for a person?

Tags: pronouns

When referring to a person, where the sex is not known, can the neuter pronoun *ĝi* be used?

Comment: I agree with Andrew. This question has already been answered in my answer to the question that Andrew linked to.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. From ReVo:

> la infano ploras, ĉar **ĝi** volas manĝi...
>
> ...ĉu **ĝi** estas vi? jes, **ĝi** estas mi...

Answer (score 3):

In general *ĝi* should only be used to refer to things that don’t have a natural gender or where the gender is considered irrelevant, such as a young child or some animals. The definition in [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#%C4%9Di) is as follows:

> Pron., uzata por referenci aŭ al senseksa realaĵo aŭ al estaĵo, kies sekson oni ne bezonas precizigi

That definition doesn’t mention cases where the sex is simply unknown, so I would say the answer to your question is “no”.

However, Zamenhof is quoted as saying *ĝi* is a possible pronoun for a person in one of the *lingvaj respondoj*:

> Kiam ni parolas pri homo, ne montrante la sekson, tiam estus regule uzi la pronomon «ĝi» (kiel ni faras ekzemple kun la vorto «infano»), kaj se vi tiel agos, vi estos gramatike tute prava. Sed ĉar la vorto «ĝi» (uzata speciale por «bestoj» aŭ «senvivaĵoj») enhavas en si ion malaltigan (kaj ankaŭ kontraŭkutiman) kaj por la ideo de «homo» ĝi estus iom malagrabla, tial mi konsilus al vi fari tiel, kiel oni faras en la aliaj lingvoj, kaj uzi por «homo» la pronomon «li».

However, I believe that usage is not very common in the modern language and instead it is more common to just use *li* (as suggested also in the *lingva respondo*) or to explicitly say *li aŭ ŝi*.

There is a growing movement towards adding the new pronoun *ri* in this case to avoid the inherent male-normative problems of using *li*.

See also the related question [Does Esperanto have a gender-neutral pronoun that can be used for humans?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/82/does-esperanto-have-a-gender-neutral-pronoun-that-can-be-used-for-humans)